# Is at appropriate to suggest to people they should vote or tick

Tags: discussion

Many questions are given (multiple) answers which seem perfectly good and yet the questioner neither votes nor ticks any, and provides no comments as to what worked or didn't.

Is it appropriate to suggest to them that they should comment, tick or upvote to help the answerers? I've taken to doing this, but I wondered if it was considered good etiquette or not.

Comment: Certainly in the case where [you are one of the answerers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935352/inserting-a-string-into-a-binary-search-tree-c) things get rather iffy. As Wooble says, such comments are pure noise. Please just don't make them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do agree with @Wooble that usually these types comments are usually nothing more than noise that distract from the question, however, I do it occasionally in specific circumstances:

- I only leave a comment if it is a relatively new user that may not be familiar with the site.  I know there are a number of prompts for new users to encourage them to upvote and accept an answer, but when it is clear they aren't doing it (asked several previous questions without an accepted answer,  "this works" comments on answers, and multiple answers without any upvotes on multiple questions), it is often helpful.  but once they accept or it appears they might have upvoted, I'll try to remember to delete to comment.
- In addition, I hardly ever leave a comment if it is a question that I am participating in as an answerer.  I don't want to seem like I am encouraging someone to upvote or accept my answer.

When I do leave a comment, I'll usually try to leave it on the question, not a specific answer unless it is in response to a "this works" comment.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, these sort of comments are just noise that add nothing to the site.

Especially in the case of asking for upvotes, how do you know the OP hasn't upvoted anything? If none of the answers have any upvotes at all, but the question has enough views that it has multiple answers, maybe the answers aren't as good as you think they are. Shouldn't you also berate the other people visiting the question for not upvoting any answers in this case?

Comment: I agree these are noise, especially _upvote my answer_ comments. There are cases especially for new users to the site, where I think directing them to [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with Wooble's answer: You do not know if the OP has upvoted something, nor if any of the questions has solved his/her problem.

However, I think it is ok to ask the OP for accepting an answer if the OP has mentioned in a comment that your answer has solved his/her problem. I also ask the OP if any answer has solved his/her problem if there are some answers and the OP has not left a comment on them saying that this is not what he/she is looking for.

Often I see this happening at questions of new users, and showing them how the site works helps also the community.