# Beggar: To be or not to be

Tags: discussion

How is adding something like

> If my answer has helped you, please accept it by ticking the green check mark

interpreted by other SO folks?

Would I be considered a beggar? Do I have the right to demand it in first place or is it totally down to the OP?

Comment: It's completely up to the OP. Please don't nag them about it. I edit it out when I see it.

Comment: You grow out of that stage soon. :)

Comment: I won't consider that as begging, I often comment on others posts that if it helped the OP, OP should accept as a correct answer, it really helps future visitors to refer an answer... Also when a user answers, he puts efforts in answering, so why not reward him with a green tick?

Comment: Most of the new comer don't know that there an 'accept answer'. So it is better if you tell them.

Comment: Related, and also a dup: [Is at appropriate to suggest to people they should vote or tick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176112/182513)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would only post such a comment given two circumstances:

1. You can clearly see the asker of the question is a new user (or hasn't accepted an answer for any of his questions), and might be not aware of the positive effects (not only to the answerer, but to the whole community) of accepting an answer to his question. If it's not the case, it's clear that if the OP hasn't accepted the answer, it isn't because he didn't know he should.
2. Enough time has passed / the OP left a comment explaining how useful the answer was, so you can be positive the answer has been really helpful and the OP isn't waiting for a better / more complete answer.

In the comment I wouldn't just ask to accept, I'd rather link to [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169503) and point out the benefits it will have for future visitors of the question to have a clearly accepted answer.

In the end it's not about you getting rep for the answer, or being a rep-whore, it's about *educating* new users.

Comment: @mehow: don't put anything like that in your answer - it doesn't belong there. Put that in a comment _if_ what Xavi explained applies.

Comment: This suggestion is what I do, I leave a comment on the question if I had no discussion with OP about the answer or in answer comments if I had. It has worked out sometimes, it has done no harm. I tend to delete these comments once the answer is accepted. It's not about being a beggar, it's about improving the way the system works (I do it on CW answers too) - having an accepted answer indicates the poster was actually able to resolve the problem. I ususally go for a much more subtle "So what did you end up doing?".

Comment: I usually ask something like "I see you didn't accepted my / any answer. Is there anything that prevents you from getting ___ done? If so, please tell." And it's about 50 / 50, either some answer gets accepted, or we get more data and I can update (or at least try to) my answer. Win / win situation for all.

Comment: the only problem with leaving a comment on SO is that their editableness expires and after a while you cannot delete a comment any longer. You can always edit your answer and remove an unnecessary sentence.

Comment: You can always delete your comments @mehow...

Comment: you are so right, i meant editing

Comment: @mehow: why is that a problem?

Comment: Im sorry @Mat, why is what the problem?

Comment: @mehow: not being able to edit comments. The "please accept" comments should plain be deleted after they've served their purpose.

Comment: oh, i thought i wasnt able to delete the comment after some time, but i was wrong. You can delete comments so its all squared